# RegEx How to match text between Multiple words regardless of their order?

Tags: javascript, regex

For a given set of words, I would like to get all the words in between inclusively.
For example :
words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit ***word2**, consectetur adipiscing elit. **word3** tristique in dolor vel consequat. Nulla tincidunt suscipit molestie. Suspendisse mauris turpis, ultricies pulvinar facilisis **word1***, vulputate sit amet . Donec cursus odio ut ipsum rutrum faucibus. Ut accumsan arcu ac ex scelerisque, ac sodales metus dictum. Nam efficitur velit sed lorem pharetra commodo.
> Morbi velit massa, feugiat nec ligula nec, finibus tincidunt nulla. Nulla a suscipit elit. Proin in nibh nec ipsum eleifend tempor.
> .

The words in Italic should be a match.

Comment: Not clear about "all the words in between inclusively". Are you asking to get the text in between the words of interest as an array (e.g. exclude the words of interest), the text and the words as an array, or just the words of interest as an array of matches?

Comment: I think the first part of @Wiktor's answer is the closest to the answer. The full string between either of the listed words including the words.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted and even closed!? "details or clarity" were obviously sufficient for an accepted answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```txt
/(word1|word2|word3).*(word1|word2|word3)/g
```

In order to account for word boundaries, so `word1randomAttachedString` would not match:

```txt
/(word1|word2|word3)\b.*\b(word1|word2|word3)/g
```

Matching only the in-between text:

```txt
/(?<=word1|word2|word3).*?(?=word1|word2|word3)/g
```

output:

- ", consectetur adipiscing elit. ",
- " tristique in dolor vel consequat. Nulla tincidunt suscipit molestie. Suspendisse mauris turpis, ultricies pulvinar facilisis "

Without lookbehind assertions that are [currently not supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=lookbehind) by Safari, it can be done using a modified expression and leaving out the first match:

```js
('x' + '…your string…')
  .match(/(?!word1|word2|word3)\b.*?(?=word1|word2|word3)/g)
  .slice(1)
```

Comment: Upvoting this as this is the closest to what should be expected, However this is not accounting for word boundaries, "word1randomaAttachedString" would still include it.

Comment: Updated the answer to account for word boundaries as well.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like [match](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) can do what you need.

This:

```
"hello from somewhere, this is a nice place".match(/(hello|this)/gi)
```

outputs:

```
[ 'hello', 'this' ]
```